# How should a scala cats IOApp acquire an ExecutionContext?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect

I've recently converted my app to inheriting cats's `IOApp` as described [here](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/datatypes/ioapp.html). I read in that documentation:

> the Timer[IO] dependency is already provided by IOApp, so on top of
>   the JVM there’s no longer a need for an implicit ExecutionContext to
>   be in scope

However, I'm interacting with several other libraries (i.e. http4s) that do require an `ExecutionContext`. Is there a recommended way to acquire one in this type of application? Does the good old `import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` play nice with that provided `Timer[IO]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try extending trait `IOApp.WithContext`. For global `ExecutionContext`

```
import cats.effect._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

object Main extends IOApp.WithContext {
  implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.global

  override protected def executionContextResource: Resource[SyncIO, ExecutionContext] =
    Resource.liftF(SyncIO(ec))

  def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {

    implicitly[Timer[IO]]
    implicitly[ContextShift[IO]]
    implicitly[ExecutionContext]

    IO.pure(ExitCode.Success)
  }
}
```

or for `ExecutionContext` from a thread pool with fixed number of threads

```
import java.util.concurrent.{Executors, TimeUnit}
import cats.effect._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

object Main extends IOApp.WithContext {
  override protected def executionContextResource: Resource[SyncIO, ExecutionContext] =
    Resource.make(SyncIO(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8)))(pool => SyncIO {
      pool.shutdown()
      pool.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    }).map(ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService)

  def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
    executionContextResource.use { implicit ec =>

      implicitly[Timer[IO]]
      implicitly[ContextShift[IO]]
      implicitly[ExecutionContext]

      SyncIO.pure(ExitCode.Success)
    }.toIO
  }
}
```

https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/issues/337

https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/pull/344

Comment: Note that is you call `executionContextResource.use` in `run`, it'll be allocated twice (once by IOApp itself - to instantiate your Timer and ContextShift, and once by you). To avoid having two ECs being allocated, use the `executionContext` method - it should give you the same EC as Timer and ContextShift are using (only available in IOApp.WithContext)